# How to interact with programs managed by pm2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

After using pm2 to manage and start a program, the program expects me to enter further instructions after performing some tasks. After using pm2 to manage and start this program, how to interact with this program?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ´pm2 attach <process_id>´

Answer (score 0):

Without code I'm not sure what kind of interactions/tasks you are performing. However you can take a look at pm2's [process-actions](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-actions/) which I think should accomplish what you're looking for